# How to hide native navigation bar?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm developing a ReactNative iOS app that starts with an ReactNative page when you enter, and after a page jump to the native page and then back again, the native navigation bar appears on the page unexpectedly.
Before entering the native page, it looks good:
[image]

After coming back from the native page，There is a native navigation at the top:
[image]

Comment: Run this on a physical Device. Check if the problem still exists or not. Because I came across this same situation. Its an emulator bug. Try once on a physical device and share the results.

Comment: My physical machine and virtual machine is the same phenomenon, I got ios colleagues to help look at it, it seems to be a problem with the ios code.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the native header:

```
  <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}> 
  ... 
  </Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: I know that this is setting the header for react navigation, but my problem is that the ios native header appears. i have found the relevant place in the ios global code, and it seems that the ios code is messing up.

Comment: I have never face this kind of issue , i'm just using the navigator and it works fine. Please share your navigation related component